# How to get index of all occurrence of the same value in an Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have two arrays like arr1, arr2. Each array having different kind of values. In array one i have repeated some values in multiple times. How can i get same value index and value? 
Also, how to get array two values from array one same value index?

```
var arr1 = [100, 200, 100, 300, 600, 200];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

For example, If my custom value is 200. arr1 result will be [1, 5]. How to get arr2 value like [2, 6].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var arr1 = [100, 200, 100, 300, 600, 200];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

var _arr1 = [];
var _arr2 = [];

for( var i = arr1.indexOf(200); i >= 0; i = arr1.indexOf(200,i+1) ) {
  _arr1.push(i);
  _arr2.push( arr2[i] );
}

console.log( _arr1, _arr2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr1 = [100, 200, 100, 300, 600, 200];
var obj={};
for(var iloop=0; iloop< arr1.length; iloop++){
   if(obj[ arr1[iloop] ]){
     obj[ arr1[iloop] ].push(iloop) ;
   }else{
     obj[ arr1[iloop] ]  = [iloop];
   }
}

for(var k in obj){
  if(obj[k] && obj[k].length>1){
    console.log(k, obj[k])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with the target array and return `true` (later also the value) if the element of `array1` with the same index is equal to the search value.

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var arr1 = [100, 200, 100, 300, 600, 200],
    arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function getMappedValues(array1, array2, value) {
    return array2.filter(function (_, i) {
        return array1[i] === value;
    });
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getMappedValues(arr1, arr2, 200), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  function findIndexes(arr, value, fromIndex, indexes)
    {
       indexes = indexes || [];
       var index = arr.indexOf(value, fromIndex+1);
       console.log(index);
       if ( index != -1)
       {
          indexes.push(index);
          findIndexes(arr, value, index, indexes)
       }
    }
    var arr1 = [100, 200, 100, 300, 600, 200];
    var arr2 = [];
    var value = 200;
    findIndexes(arr1, value, -1, arr2);
    document.write(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is go through the array 1 and once find your custom value

- Put that index into one array
- Get value from array 2 in that index and put it to another array

Here is the code

```
    var arr1 = [100, 200, 100, 300, 600, 200];
    var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    var index=[];
    var result=[];

    var customValue=200;

    for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
      if(arr1[i]==customValue){
        result.push(arr2[i]);
        index.push(i);
      }
    }
    console.log(index);
    console.log(result);
```